# fpdf bug in IE7

Tags: php, html, pdf, fpdf

I am using fpdf in my webpage where user can assign values in the webpage and pdf prints these values.The code works fine and pdf also generates the problem is when i change the values and save the values to database, when the pdf generates it shows the old values of the database. I've tried deleting the pdf file from the server before generating new pdf but still it doesn't work. this only happens in IE and older version of firefox. It works fine in Firefox 25 and Chrome. Can somebody tell me whats the problem here, My code is:

```
$pdf=new HTML2FPDF();
$pdf->SetMargins(25,10,25);
$pdf->AddPage(); 

$cresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customer_id = '$id'");
while ($crow = mysql_fetch_array($cresult)) {
$html = '//HTML ';
}
$pdf->WriteHTML($html);
$pdf->Output("Ticket.pdf"); 
$file=fopen("Ticket.pdf","r");
header("Location://url");
```

Comment: IE7 is probably caching the PDF. If you do Ctrl+F5 then do you get the latest pdf?

Comment: took your suggestion,did that... but doesnot work.Thanks anyways.

Comment: When IE saves the data the second time, does the database reflect the new data?

Comment: the new data is stored in the database if that's what you mean. It displays in the page just not in the pdf.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Can you try putting `header('Expires: Mon, 1 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');` before `$pdf->Output("Ticket.pdf");`?

Comment: the pdf page comes blank when i use that code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42805/discussion-between-rajen-shrestha-and-monkeyzeus)